# how to sum and display with button

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-button

```
    for(int x = 1; x < i ; x++){
        int id =1000;
        // VIEWS
         TextView tvx = new TextView(this);
         EditText etx = new EditText(this);
         EditText editx = new EditText(this);
         // ADD VIEW
        //set properties

        ll1.addView(tvx);
        ll1.addView(etx);
        ll1.addView(editx);
            // sets the ingredient  and the amount and cal corresponding

        switch(x){

        case 1: tvx.setText("Chicken");
                etx.setText("200");
                editx.setText("100");

                etx.setId(x);
                editx.setId(id);

            break;
        case 2:tvx.setText("eggs");
                etx.setText("350");
                editx.setText("100");
                etx.setId(x);
                editx.setId(id);
            break;
        case 3:tvx.setText("Bacon");
                etx.setText("400");
                editx.setText("100");
                etx.setId(x);
                editx.setId(id);

            break;
        case 4:
            tvx.setText("Salad");
            etx.setText("200");
            etx.setId(x);
            editx.setId(id);
            editx.setText("100");
            break;
        }



        //  // // // // // // // 

 id++;



    }

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        Button btn3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn3);  
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            int id = 1000;
            for(int v = 1 ; v < i ; v++){
            EditText et1 = (EditText)findViewById(v);   
            EditText et2 = (EditText)findViewById(id);  

            id++;
        int sum = 0;    
        sum += Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
            btn3.setText(""+sum);

            }
        }



    });
}
```

hey guys how do i sum up the numbers of the et1? because the sum displayed on the button is just the value of the first edit text.

is there something wrong with my first for loop while setting the id or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to sum the values in the text fields you are going to have to add the value of both text fields, not just one.

Your code:

```
int sum = 0;    
sum += Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
```

Summing values of both text fields:

```
int sum = 0;    
sum += Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
sum += Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString());
```